# SSIS - How do I join two sources on a complex expression?

Tags: ssis, dataflow

I have one data source which has a column Part_Number.

My second data source has Product_Family_ID, Product_ID and Part_Mask.

Mask is a pattern string used in a like expression where part_number like mask.  For instance 'NXA%' or '001-[abcd][456]9-121%'

Usually we look up legitimate part numbers for a product family based on the available product part masks, but in this instance I need to go in the other direction.  Based on a part number, I must find all the related products in that product family and store that in a summary table.

Simulating this in T-SQL:

```
declare @partlist table (partnumber varchar(100))

insert into @partlist (partnumber) values ('nxampvg1')

select distinct pl.partnumber, match.Product_ID
from @partlist pl
join (  select m.masks, p.product_id from  MCS_ProductFamily_PartMasks m
    join Product p on m.ProductFamilyID = p.ProductFamily_ID) match
    on pl.partnumber like match.Masks
```

Desired output:

```
Part_Number Product_ID
----------- ----------
nxampvg1    15629
nxampvg1    15631
nxampvg1    15632
nxampvg1    15633
nxampvg1    15634
nxampvg1    15635
nxampvg1    15636
nxampvg1    15637
nxampvg1    15638
nxampvg1    15639
```

How can I accomplish this in an SSIS data flow task?

Comment: I don't think I am seeing enough of your data to understand your question. Perhaps a bit of data from the source with the part number and two rows from the second data source: one with a matching mask and one without would help my feeble brain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 data sources, one that gets all the part numbers from source one and another that gets all the product id's, product family's and masks using the inner query
`select m.masks, p.product_id from  MCS_ProductFamily_PartMasks m
    join Product p on m.ProductFamilyID = p.ProductFamily_ID` 
from source two. The data destinations for these should be staging tables on the same sql server. Then simply use a derivation of the SQL you stated in your example in such a way: `select distinct pl.partnumber, match.Product_ID
from STG_SOURCE_ONE pl
join STG_SOURCE_TWO match
    on pl.partnumber like match.Masks`

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.